# Javascript/flash load external URL HTML

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, flash

I have looked around and it seems that there is no way whatsoever to load external/remote URLs like http://google.com through the client browser using Javascript without using a proxy be it a PHP file in the server side or YQL which essentially uses the Yahoo API as a proxy. This is due to the same-origin policy.

I am not versed in Flash and I think that it might hold an answer because even though some people are agressively phasing it out, it has a lot of power.

My question: is there something I missed when searching? Free hosts have some restrictions on the amount of requests and the load on the server per unit time and I wouldn't like to get kicked out. Also my site scrapes some remote site's data so I wouldn't like to get blocked which I would get if I used a PHP proxy. So is there a simple **Flash** solution or Javascript solution I did not see?

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible due to the `Same origin policy`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy

Comment: I acknowledged that in my question...my question is if somebody had a flash or Javascript workaround I was unaware of that did not require a proxy but only used the client-browser to load everything.